# DataGrid sets all items to same value , when i want to change only 1 item

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

when i try to set a specific Item in dataGrid , it changes all other item's values to that same value. I'm not sure if it's a bug or i done something wrong. Here is my code:
(Datagrid is in another window (Main window), so i called a function in that window to edit the value)

```
private void AAbutton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{    
    Account selected = new Account();
    if (textBox2.Text != null)
        selected.username = textBox2.Text;
    if (textBox12.Text != null)
        selected.password = textBox12.Text;
    if (locationTxtBox2.Text != null)
        selected.location = locationTxtBox2.Text;
    MainWindow.Instance.editAccount(selected);
    MainWindow.Instance.updateData();
    MainWindow.Instance.needsSave = true;
}
```

And here is the function in the main window:

```
public void editAccount(Account acc)
{
    Account acc2;
    Account selected = (Account)dataGrid.SelectedItem;
    acc2 = Manager.accounts.ElementAt(Manager.accounts.FindIndex(a=> a == selected));
    acc2.username = acc.username;
    acc2.password = acc.password;
    acc2.location = acc.location;
}
```

I really couldn't find a solution for this problem.

And here is the Account class in case you need it:

```
public class Account
{
    public String username { get; set; }
    public String password { get; set; }
    public String location { get; set; }
    public Account(String username,String password, String location)
    {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.location = location;
    }
    public Account()
    {

    }
}
```

Just to mention , i use Mahapps.metro controls.

Comment: How do you populate Manager.accounts? Can we see that code? I'm going to make a wild guess that the properties that initially appear on all instances of Account are the properties of the last row you read from the databas. I'd also like to see the XAML for your DataGrid, including all bindings.

Comment: It's a list , so i just add another instance in it from another window, here is code:

Comment: private void AAbutton1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            String username = textBox.Text;
            String password = textBox1.Text;
            String location = locationTxtBox.Text;
            Manager.accounts.Add(new Account(username,password,location));
            MainWindow.Instance.updateData();
            MainWindow.Instance.needsSave = true;
        }

Comment: Please add the code to your question. You can edit your question and add to it. Please show us how Manager.accounts is defined as well. In the question, not in a comment.

Comment: Are you saying the *only* way Accounts are ever added to Manager.accounts is in AAbutton1_Click? Don't you already have a different definition of AAbutton1_Click above?

Comment: It's a different window, wait few minutes please, i will upload whole project to github

Comment: @EdPlunkett Here: github.com/Po2kkz/Simple-accounts-manager

Comment: Just to clarify, are you saying that when you create a new account named "Bob", the name of every account in the grid changes to "Bob"? I thought that was what you were saying, but I'm starting to wonder.

Comment: Yeah, not just name but password and location too. And little weirt thing, they become white, and when i go with mouse over them then i can see them.

Comment: By the way, you need to use ObservableCollection instead of List, and Account needs to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. Then you can get rid of this updateData() thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was right! I read your mind.

This isn't a WPF question, a binding question, or a DataGrid question. It's a "how do references work in C#?" question. It's a good question.

On file load, you start with a list of encrypted Accounts, but in decryption, you copy all the decrypted properties of each one of the accounts into the same instance of Account, and add that one instance multiple times to the list. The decrypted ones are all the same instance. You start off OK, but then you go off the rails in DecryptAccounts().

Here's the bug:

```
public static void DecryptAccounts()
{
    //  Hmmm. What's he planning to do with this?
    Account holder = new Account(null, null, null);

    accounts.Clear();

    foreach (Account acc in Encryptedaccounts)
    {
        //  HERE IT IS. This is the same instance of holder on every
        //  iteration. After file load, every Account in accounts is the 
        //  same object as every other. 

        //  You need to create a new Account object for each account. 

        holder.username = Decrypt(acc.username, user.Decryptedpassword);
        holder.password = Decrypt(acc.password, user.Decryptedpassword);
        holder.location = Decrypt(acc.location, user.Decryptedpassword);
        accounts.Add(holder);
    }
}

public static void LoadFromFile()
{
    if (File.Exists(Path.Combine(appdata, folder, file)))
    {
        Encryptedaccounts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Account>>(File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(appdata, folder, file)));
    }
    DecryptAccounts();
}
```

## Here's the fix

Manager.cs

```
public Account DecryptAccount(Account acc)
{
    return new Account {
        username = Decrypt(acc.username, user.Decryptedpassword),
        password = Decrypt(acc.password, user.Decryptedpassword),
        location = Decrypt(acc.location, user.Decryptedpassword)
    };
}

public static void DecryptAccounts()
{
    accounts.Clear();

    foreach (Account acc in Encryptedaccounts)
    {
        accounts.Add(DecryptAccount(acc));
    }
}

//  You've got the same issue here

private static void EncryptAccounts()
{
    Encryptedaccounts.Clear();
    foreach (Account acc in accounts)
    {
        Encryptedaccounts.Add(EncryptAccount(acc));
    }
}

public Account EncryptAccount(Account acc)
{
    return new Account {
        username = Encrypt(acc.username, user.Decryptedpassword),
        password = Encrypt(acc.password, user.Decryptedpassword),
        location = Encrypt(acc.location, user.Decryptedpassword)
    };
}
```

Some other issues here. Not bugs, but life will be easier if you do stuff the "proper WPF way":

`Manager.accounts` should be of type `ObservableCollection<Account>`. Then it will automatically notify the DataGrid whenever you add or remove items from it and you won't have to do this `updateData()` thing to manually refresh the grid all the time.

`Manager` and `Account` both ought to implement [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) and fire notifications on their properties when their values change. In C#6, this is very simple:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.ComponentModel;

//  ... snip ...

public event PropertyChanged;

protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = null)
{
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
}
```

Then your properties look like this:

```
private String _username = null;
public String username { 
    get { return _username; } 
    set {
        if (value != _username)
        {
            _username = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    } 
}
```

When they do that, anything you bind them to in the UI will be notified whenever you change the values. You'll be able to set properties on the selected grid item and the UI will update without any grid refresh or anything -- it'll just know. Very convenient.

Comment: @ToniPejic My pleasure.